# override frontend with custom text

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using a plugin called [YITH WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing And Discounts] to create discount based on quantity rules and display them in a tiered-price table, I have 3 rules:

- (1-5)
- (6-11)
- (12+)

[Screenshot explaining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df0xh.jpg)

I want to override the frontend with custom text for each instead of the quantity numbers (from X to X).
I have contacted  the support and they told me to override the plugin template and make changes to this part of the code

```html
<table id="ywdpd-table-discounts" class="<?php echo $template; ?>">
    <?php if ( 'horizontal' === $template ) : ?>
        <tr class="quantity_row">
            <th><?php echo wp_kses_post( $label_quantity ); ?></th>
            <?php foreach ( $rules as $rule ) : ?>
                <td class="qty-info" data-qtymin="<?php echo esc_attr( $rule['min_quantity'] ); ?>"
                    data-qtymax="<?php echo esc_attr( $rule['max_quantity'] ); ?>">
                    <?php

                    $minQ = $rule['min_quantity'];
                    $maxQ = '';
                    if ( $rule['max_quantity'] !== $rule['min_quantity'] ) {
                        $maxQ = ( '*' !== $rule['max_quantity'] ) ? '-' . $rule['max_quantity'] : '+';
                    }

                    echo esc_html( $rule['min_quantity'] . $maxQ );
                    ?>

                </td>
            <?php endforeach ?>
```

Full php file in Github - https://github.com/Alnaggar94/public/blob/main/yith_ywdpd_table_pricing.php
could anyone please help me with that? or show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: `$rule['min_quantity'] . $maxQ` will contain the text that you actually see, so it’ll be `1-5` up to `16+`, so you could use that to create the association to your replacement tests (using that value as an array index.) You could also check what else `$rule` contains, maybe there is something like an ID or a rule name, that could be used as well. If you want to hard-code these replacement text in this location, then a simple array would do; if you want to have them configurable in the site options or something like that, then you’d have to delve into the whole thing a little deeper.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, They also suggest using an id. but every rule has 2 ids. check this screenshot - https://ibb.co/bPbXDV9  How can I edit the code based on that id ?

Comment: These are IDs in HTML, that was probably not what they meant. In the `$rules` array that the code above is looping over, ever rule will probably have an ID in some extra field, or there will at least be the array index, that a specific rule could be identified by.

Comment: I have contact theme and there reply was (In the template there is a foreach for process all rules.
You have a the $rule variable that is an array.

With $rule['id'] you can get the id) So now how can I get the right id for the rule and assign each id with spical label?

Comment: Well as they said, you get the ID via `$rule['id']` inside the foreach loop. You could put your label texts into an array, using those IDs as keys. And then inside the loop, you get the matching entry from your array, and output it as content of the table cell generated there.